# ASP.NET - How do I authenticate against multiple APIs?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, microservices

So, I have 3 microservices and only 1 of them is used for Authentication - it uses ASP.NET Identity.

I am issuing a token every time successful login occurs, which contains claims such as Id, Username, Balance (money), Roles.

When this JWT is created how can I pass it to other APIs? Is it necessary to use API Gateway or not? Is it bad practice to store it in local storage?

If it is not necessary, can I store this JWT as Cookie and pass it to my other APIs?
And if so -> how can I create some kind of session in my other APIs, depending on that cookie?

I am very confused on 2 main topics - how other APIs will know about this token and how in each API I can create authenticated/ authorized session, because most of the tutorials use Postman and on each request they pass this auth/ bearer token. But this is not applicable in real world situations, at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, implement an 'API Gateway' [I'd used Ocelot- opensoure].
Handle all the authentication/authorization/Security checks at your gateway itself before calling any of the microservice (n).
To summarize

1. Create API Gateway with ocelot configuration
2. Implement JWT tokens ( based on need you can have different tokens like User Token/App based token etc)
3. Generate and pass the token into the header request from client(UI).
4. The request reaches API Gateway where authentication/authorization takes place and if valid, the request is passed to the corresponding downstream microservice.
5. You can implement cache to enhance performance accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this is what I already did, since some time passed.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of creating JWT auth in every API, First implement API
  gateway and intergrate JWT stuff in that API Gate way.
- API gateway will authenticate all api calls and will send requests
  according their endpoints.
- In my real scenario we are Used **Ocelot API gate way** and it is
  open source.